# pandas dataframe to append same value for multiple different row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe lets say PR which holds planvol and actualvol columns data. and I have another dataframe lets call it as hub which holds value as 'CRNBJ'. Now i want to append hub dataframe with the PR dataframe as new column as hub after planvol and actual vol columns

```
 PR = pd.read_excel(input_file_path ,sheet_name='Daily Operating Plan' ,usecols= 'I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W' ) 
PR= PR.iloc[[10,14,17,27,35,40,45,50]] 
#print(PR)
```

I want to add another datafrme value(hub= CRNBJ) to the PR dataframe

```
hub = df['hub']
    print (hub) 
output: CRNBJ
```

how can I add CRNBJ value to the other row values of planvol and actualvol

**desired output**

```
 planvol actualvol  hub
 10        20      CRNBJ
 11        21      CRNBJ
 12        22      CRNBJ
```

Comment: where does the planvol, actualvol comes from? your question is not clear. refer to the guidelines here   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: posted an answer, guessing if that is what you want. take a look

Comment: i have a new df lets say called PR which holds planvol and actualvol columns data as mentioned in my question. Now i want to add hub dataframe value to the PR dataframe with new column as hub and its values are CRNBJ

Comment: I added an answer, does that work?

Comment: no . its inserting integer values in the hub column

Comment: what is the value in **hub** variable?

Comment: it works for me in a made up scenario. Check the hub variable

Comment: PR = pd.read_excel(input_file_path
                        ,sheet_name='Daily Operating Plan'
                        ,usecols= 'I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W'
                        )
PR= PR.iloc[[10,14,17,27,35,40,45,50]]
#print(PR)

i want to add another datafrme value(hub= CRNBJ) to the PR dataframe

Comment: i updated solution below and defined the value for the hub variable. Is that still not working?

Answer (score 0):

is that what you're looking for to insert a column?

```
# insert a new column at the end, named hub and value what in hub variable

hub='CRNBJ'

df.insert(len(df.columns),'**hub**', hub)
df
```